# getRangeByName stopped working! Document corrupted or known issue?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

As referenced here (https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2589), calling getRangeByName stopped working on documents that were perfectly working until now. Is this a known issue? How to fix this? I've seen reports about people complaining about the "instability" of this method that would stop working at time. This is a problem for us as we are using this extensively to populate company dashboards!

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

**SheetName**!rangename

i.e. add the sheet name to your named range. I was setting this with code, not sure if it works from the UI. When I switched to this way, my problems with named ranges went away.

Background:
With only one sheet, all worked fine, but having a few sheets caused problems. I think it was caused when I duplicated sheets with names ranges in. Adding the sheet name solved the problem. Also deleting all the named ranges and adding them again solved the problem.

Comment: You rock Eddy! This was exactly my issue i.e. I had duplicated sheets, renamed some, etc. However the range deletion/creation didn't quite work for me. Anyway, your trick worked. One additional comment, if your sheet name has a space in it, then call the formula using
`ss.getRangeByName("Sheet With Space!MyRange")`
 with no apostrophes around the sheet name, otherwise it won't work

Comment: See related question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159487/27487